# How to chunk() with a view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, chunking

Laravel 5.6

The problem I'm trying to solve is to take a set of instructions (table #1) and compare it with a set of known information (table #2).

The final outcome is that the known information must be up to date - matching the instructions, record for record. And it requires user intervention.

- So I can easily retrieve any records with discrepancies. There will be hundreds of records with issues.
- I can also easily retrieve a chunk, say 1 at a time.  And I can then pass it to a view for the user to deal with.

But I can't figure out how to return to the chunking bit for the next item. If I call the same method again, I'm going to start from the first record again. And sometimes some issues need to be skipped over to deal with later.

If on the other hand I just load 5,000 records and pass them to the view to deal with, I'm going to create a memory overhead which could be unpleasant.

Is there another technique I could look at?

The only other approach I think is to create an interim view where all the items are put into a view, so that the complete list of rows with issues is shown, allowing the user to select one spevcific item from the list to resolve.

Comment: Can't you compare the tables with SQL and return just the relevant results? Dealing with comparisons in view doesn't seem like a good idea. Can you provide some code so that we have some idea of what you're dealing with here?